# Teaching logic through "high school algebra"?

Tags: algebra, proofs, logic, discrete-math

I am going to be teaching a discrete math class in the fall.  One of the major goals of the course is a solid understanding of the basics of logic: the precise meanings of "and", "or", "not", "implies", "if and only if", "there exists", and "for each"  and how to logically manipulate statements involving these.

Often Discrete Math tries to illustrate all of these concepts in the context of set theory, graph theory, combinatorics, elementary number theory, etc.  This has the disadvantage that the student is learning new content at the same time they are trying to master the basic logical ideas.

Logic is ubiquitous in mathematics, so I figure that I should be able to illustrate all of these concepts in a **familiar** mathematical setting: namely "high school algebra".

An example: does the first line imply the second line, does the second line imply the first line, or both ?

$$
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 2x \tag 1\\
x &= 2\tag 2
\end{align*}
$$

I am sure that I could come up with "algebra problems" which illustrate all of the concepts I am trying to convey.  For instance, partial fraction decomposition is a fairly logically complex idea (you want to find the only values of some variables ($A$, $B$, $C$ , etc) which make an equation true **for all $x$**).

My questions:

1. Does anyone have any textbooks which would fit well with what I am trying to do?  This could either be a book on logic or discrete math which already does what I am proposing, or a book on high school algebra which pays careful attention to logic.
2. Has this idea been tried before?  In particular, is there any relevant research on this approach?

Comment: Is your discrete math class an upper division course with a prerequisite, or is it a lower division course, more akin to “finite math?” Also, who is the main audience, perhaps computer science majors?

Comment: @user52817  This is a sophomore  level course for math and computer science majors.  This course is being taught in 4 or 5 radically different ways by the instructors who teach it (we are trying to work on that...).  I have not taught discrete yet, but I have taught courses which require it as a prerequisite, like abstract algebra.  I have not found that my students are being well prepared by it.  For instance, hardly any of them know that to prove an "if and only if" statement, that they have to prove both directions.

Comment: To be clear, I would still be covering set theory, graph theory, etc.  I just think maybe the first 3 weeks or so out of 15 I could devote to learning logic in the context of high school algebra.

Comment: Coincidentally, I am also teaching Discrete Math for sophomore CS & math majors for the first time this fall. Also being head of assessment, the one red-flag that consistently pops up for the last 4 years is that students are very weak at proving *anything* at the end of this course (likely the first having asked for proof work). I think one option is to really make proof-writing a consistent top goal of the course. Another: I've had a proof-writing workshop for math majors added to the curriculum (starting Fall 2019).

Comment: Closer to the stated question: Somewhere around here I recall someone stating they tried to have "rigorous college algebra", including logic and proofs, as the first course for math majors. That warms my heart, but it didn't sound very successful, as the institutional expectation was that students should be beyond algebra at that point, etc. Here we're using Rosen's Discrete Mathematics, and many of the initial examples are usually algebraic (say, the first out of any block of 6 examples or so). Keep in mind that the set, graph theory, etc., is itself a core part of the curriculum.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins If you can find any more information about that "rigorous college algebra" course, I would be really grateful.  I agree that set theory, graph theory, etc absolutely need solid coverage.  I just think I could cover them after an initial "rigorous college algebra" experience lasting about 3 weeks.

Comment: I think you may find that throwing even high-school algebra into the mix will cause more confusion with its own long list of hidden rules and axioms. May I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with my Windows-based freeware available at dcproof.com There, I introduce the rules of propositional and predicate logic using only proofs in logic and the most elementary set theory, keeping the number of rules and axioms to a minimum. Three weeks should be ample time to cover this introductory course

Comment: @user541 It is possible that they will base their proofs on their own "personal experience" with algebra rather than on explicitly stated axioms and rules and later wonder why that doesn't work in,say, abstract algebra. See F.A. Ersoz, “Proof in different mathematical domains,” Proceedings of the ICMI Study 19 Conference, Volume 1, 2009 http://140.122.140.1/~icmi19/files/Volume_1.pdf

Comment: This is an old question, but someone pointed me to it recently. Have you heard of [How to Prove It](https://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Approach-2nd/dp/0521675995) by Daniel Velleman? It is an excellent book that teaches basic logical reasoning as the core part of mathematics. And recently he published another book, [Calculus: A Rigorous First Course](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/calculus-a-rigorous-first-course). I have [commented on that review](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161?m=50568133#50568133) recently too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, one place to look is in the huge amount of “new math” curriculum material that was written during the late 1950s to early 1970s, but I’ll leave that for you or someone else to search through.

Regarding the papers listed below, I looked through a lot of papers that I've collected over the years on elementary logic issues (far more than what’s below) and I’ve singled out some papers that might be worth looking at. I’ve divided these papers into two categories: **(A)** $7$ papers in which I saw some explicit connection with high school algebra topics being made (identified by italic bold numbers --- ***[9]***, ***[16]***, ***[18]***, ***[19]***, ***[21]***, ***[23]***, ***[29]***), and **(B)** the remaining $22$ papers, which seem to have something of possible pedagogical interest for what you’re dealing with, even though they do not appear to make any explicit connection with high school algebra topics. I googled the titles to find the digital versions I’ve given links to, but nearly all of them are behind paywalls. There might be some papers that I’ve given a paywall link to that can be found elsewhere not behind a paywall, but I did not put any effort into looking for this.

**[1]** Oliver D. Anderson, [*How many Venn diagrams are there?*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739880190208?journalCode=tmes20), **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 19 #2 (1988), 299-305.

**[2]** Oliver D. Anderson, *A universal Venn diagram*, **Mathematics and Computer Education** 22 #2 (Spring 1988), 78-80.

**[3]** Keith Austin, *Set algebra: word proofs and Venn diagrams*, **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 18 #3 (1987), 482-484.

**[4]** Christopher Baltus, [*A truth table on the island of truthtellers and liars*](http://sheilamorr.weebly.com/uploads/5/6/8/0/5680346/frederixon_cs1_articlefortask.pdf), **Mathematics Teacher** 94 #9 (December 2001), 730-732.

**[5]** Margaret E. Baron, [*A note on the historical development of logic diagrams: Leibniz, Euler and Venn*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614533), **Mathematical Gazette** 53 #383 (May 1969), 113-125.

**[6]** John D. Baum, [*An arithmetic method in symbolic logic*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615252), **Mathematical Gazette** 56 #396 (May 1972), 91-95.

**[7]** Javad Behboodian, *Set identities and set equations*, **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 22 #1 (1991), 123-126.

**[8]** Max Black, [*The relevance of mathematical philosophy to the teaching of mathematics*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3607475), **Mathematical Gazette** 22 #249 (May 1938), 149-163.

***[9]*** Brother T. Brendan, [*A popular fallacy*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1959.tb08254.x), **School Science and Mathematics** 59 #7 (October 1959), 509-513.

**[10]** Arthur H. Copeland, [*The algebra of logic*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24345108), **Pi Mu Epsilon Journal** 2 #7 (Fall 1957), 317-323.

**[11]** Carmine DeSanto, *A classroom note on Venn diagrams for four and five sets*, **Mathematics and Computer Education** 18 #2 (Spring 1984), 107-110.

**[12]** Melvin Fitting, *Propositional logic using elementary algebra*, **Mathematics and Computer Education** 16 #3 (Fall 1982), 204-207. [related to Goodstein’s paper]

**[13]** Reuben Louis Goodstein, *Solving equations in the algebra of classes*, **Mathematical Spectrum** 2 #1 (1969-1970), 25-28. [related to Fitting’s paper]

**[14]** David W. Henderson, [*Venn diagrams for more than four classes*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311865), **American Mathematical Monthly** 70 #4 (April 1963), 424-426.

**[15]** Clive Kelly, *Set algebra via Boolean functions*, **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 20 #3 (1989), 478-480.

***[16]*** Ernest Albert Kuehls, [*The truth-value of* $\{\forall, \; \exists, \; P(x,y)\}:$ *a graphical approach*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688742), **Mathematics Magazine** 43 #5 (November 1970), 260-261.

**[17]** B. Meltzer, [*Mathematics, logic and undecidability*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3613605), **Mathematics Gazette** 51 #375 (February 1967), 16-25. [See [*Corrigendum*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614388) in **MG** 51 #376, May 1967, p. 134.]

***[18]*** Karl Menger, [*On necessary and on sufficient conditions in elementary mathematics*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1939.tb03989.x), **School Science and Mathematics** 39 #7 (October 1939), 631-642.

***[19]*** Kenneth A. Retzer, [*Logic, tradition, truth in algebra, and inferences for geometry*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1984.tb09539.x), **School Science and Mathematics** 84 #3 (March 1984), 181-188.

**[20]** Kenneth A. Retzer, [*Proofs with visible inference schemes*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1984.tb09564.x), **School Science and Mathematics** 84 #5 (May-June 1984), 367-376.

***[21]*** Joseph V. Roberti, [*The indirect method*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27965222), **Mathematics Teacher** 80 #1 (January 1987), 41-43.

**[22]** Mariano Rodrigues, *Coding Venn diagrams*, **Mathematics and Computer Education** 15 #1 (Winter 1981), 46-49.

***[23]*** Myron Frederick Rosskopf and Robert M. Exner, [*Some concepts of logic and their application in elementary mathematics*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27954897), **Mathematics Teacher** 48 #5 (May 1955), 290-298.

**[24]** M. Stephanie, [*Venn diagrams*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27956754), **Mathematics Teacher** 56 #2 (February 1963), 98-101.

**[25]** Ian Stewart, [*The truth about Venn diagrams*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615644), **Mathematical Gazette** 60 #411 (March 1976), 47-54.

**[26]** Charles W. Tryon, [*The logic of implication*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1949-8594.1973.tb08961.x), **School Science and Mathematics** 73 #1 (January 1973), 56-60.

**[27]** C. H. Wild, [*The "characteristic function" and set theory*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3613800), **Mathematical Gazette** 54 #389 (October 1970), 296-297.

**[28]** Margaret Wiscamb, [*Graphing true-false statements*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27958215), **Mathematics Teacher** 62 #7 (November 1969), 553-556.

***[29]*** John D. Wiseman, [*Complex contrapositives*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27968038), **Mathematics Teacher** 58 #4 (April 1965), 323-326.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks amazing!  It will take a while to read all of these...

Answer (score -1):

My advice is to teach basic Boolean stuff, with an EE slant.

FWIW, I have never had a course in this stuff, but at least have the very very basics from Ne Math and from EE survey course (for general engineers).  I was working at McKinsey, where in theory we do "issue trees" but rarely do.  I was told to sketch out a problem once in an issue tree before a partner discussion, did it with and and or gates (abnormal for McK and often causing issues in the though process).  Partner liked it.  So maybe there is use in places other than strict logic or EE or the like.